# Size of a random forest model in MLlib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

I have to compute and to keep in memory several (e.g. 20 or more) random forests model with Apache Spark.

I have only 8 GB available on the driver of the yarn cluster I use to launch the job. And I am faced to `OutOfMemory` errors because models do not fit in memory. I have already decreased the ratio `spark.storage.memoryFraction` to 0.1 to try to increase the non-RDD memory.

I have thus two questions:

- How could I make these models fit in memory?
- What could I check the size of my models?

**EDIT**

I have 200 executors which have 8GB of space.

I am not sure my models live in the driver but I suspect it as I get `OutOfMemory` errors and I have plenty of space in the executors. Furthermore, I stock these models in `Arrays`

Comment: This question needs more details. What is the size of your executors? How many executors do you have? Why do your models live in the driver?